# How do I remove MavensMate completely?

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I would like to know how I can remove MavensMate from my Sublime Text application.
I am aware of the uninstall package via Package Control, however I remember installing MavensMate API too, by removing the package will this also be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a brief look at the mavensmate code. What install Mavensmate API does is it creates a Mavensmate folder under your sublime's package\User folder and everything is inside there. By removing that folder you can remove Mavensmate API. In windows, it is usually under c:\users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User. I am not sure about other systems. But you can easily find it out by Tools > new plugin, save, the default folder is the package\user folder.

Package control > remove package will only remove the sublime package under installed package or the folder under packages. So it will not remove the mm APIs.

Comment: so how can we remove the mavensmate plugin and re-install?

Comment: @peevesy Things are very different now since the time I wrote this answer. Nowadays I believe you only need to remove the plugin from sublime and reinstall.